# How to calculate confidence intervals for Precision & Recall (from a signal detection matrix)?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, signal-detection

I built a detector to detect a binary outcome and then took a random sample from the population.  From this, I can create a signal detection/confusion matrix (hit, miss, false alarm, correct rejection) [aka: TP, FP, FN, TN] and then calculate metrics such as Recall and Precision.

My question: How do you calculate confidence intervals for the Recall and Precision of the population from which I sampled?

I was thinking of this formula: 
p - z * sqrt(p*(1-p)/n) < p < p + z * sqrt(p*(1-p)/n)

where p = the statistic (e.g., Recall) and z = z-score for the desired confidence

Answer (score 4):

I'll summarise the approaches which are sketched by the other two answers.

1. **Suggest by @marsu.** Assume that your confusion matrix $C$ has a multinomial distribution $M(n; π)$, then the distribution of the $TP$ is binomial. Assume a symmetric beta prior for precision $p$ and and recall $r$, that is $p,r ∼ Beta(λ, λ)$. Then given your data $D$ the posterior for $p$ is $p|D ∼ Beta(TP + \lambda, FP + \lambda)$ and $r$ is $r|D ∼ Beta(TP + \lambda, FN + \lambda)$. You can then use software to calculate the appropriate confidence interval as outlined here: [Calculate the confidence interval for the mean of a beta distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82475/calculate-the-confidence-interval-for-the-mean-of-a-beta-distribution).
2. **Suggest by @fred.** Generate $D_n$ datasets by sampling with replacement from your underlying dataset $D$. For each $D_n$ fit your classifier, and calculate the confusion matrix $C_n$. For each $C_n$ calculate precision $p_n$  and $r_n$, the confidence interval for these quantities can be calculated directly from the bootstrap distribution.

Comment: An alternative to the bootstrap approach in option (2) is to use the jackknife. For jackknife estimates of variance and standard errors of a given statistic (e.g. mean), see e.g. Efron, B. and Tibshirani, R.J., 1994. "An Introduction to the Bootstrap", p 141. Note that the jackknife should not be used for non-smooth statistics where a small change to the data could cause a large change in the statistic like for example in the median (or any other quantile).

Comment: Thanks for the insightful discussion and the distinction between frequentist and bayesian approaches. I am facing a similar question of comparing models, and have a question about the sampling. Assuming I have `training` and `test` sets, should I be sampling $D_n$ datasets only from the `training` set, or from both of them separately?

Answer (score 3):

An answer here suggests using bootstrapped statistics; we've done this at my place of employment and it seems to do the right thing.

[Confidence interval for precision and recall in classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117892/confidence-interval-for-precision-and-recall-in-classification?rq=1)

Comment: Please include the details of the link in the answer to help avoid reads from having to click on the link. As it stands, this looks more like a comment.

Comment: The link that you posted doesn't have any answer now.

Answer (score 3):

The following approach might be more accurate and more efficient.

[Goutte, C., & Gaussier, E. (2005, March). A probabilistic interpretation of precision, recall and F-score, with implication for evaluation. In European Conference on Information Retrieval (pp. 345-359). Springer Berlin Heidelberg.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.64.142&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: in addition to providing a reference, please briefly explain why this approach would be better

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the approach described in the paper suggested by **@Marsu_** is a Bayesian rather than a frequentist one. This means that the intervals it provides, despite what the article claims, are **credible intervals**, not the **confidence** ones; and those are in fact very different in interpretation.

The Bayesian approach is assuming that the parameter of interest is a random variable having a prior distribution, and the credible interval bounds are fixed as encompassing a given probability mass of the posterior distribution of that parameter. The prior is chosen through some considerations external to the inference problem; the article itself suggests several alternatives.

From the frequentist standpoint, the parameter is constant and the interval bounds are random variables; the confidence level represents how often on average the true value of the parameter will fall into the resulting confidence interval if the sample was re-drawn multiple times from the distribution.

See [Credible interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval) and [Confidence interval: Meaning and interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Meaning_and_interpretation) for more information.

So it seems the only remaining options for proper *confidence intervals* are resampling-based methods like bootstrap or jackknife proposed by others.